# Does Spyne support proxies?

Tags: python, spyne

I would like to use Spyne to call ASP.Net web services with SOAP. Does Spyne support proxies?

(I'm using Python 2.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spyne is not that good of a solution as a Soap client. I'd suggest you to look at [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/).